# what parameter should be noticed in design sample and hold circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, accuracy

if I want to sample from a pulse with 50kHz frequency, that changing between -5 and +5 Volt, what parameter should be considered in choosing op amp to get high accuracy, and How should I calculate my accuracy of the circuit.
Consider That I use switch with 25ohm turn on resistance,and my circuit something like this :
[image]

Comment: Since an op-amp is high impedance input, the 25 Ohm between the parts isn't a problem.

Comment: OK, so you've got a pulse at 50 kHz. What is the pulse width? And  just exactly what do you mean by "high accuracy"? 1%? 0.1%, 0.01%? 8 bits? 12 bits?

Answer (score 2):

As with any sample and hold, you need an opamp that introduces minimal errors from its input offset voltage, its input bias currents and its leakage impedance to ground. Most modern opamps specify these parameters.

You also need to ensure that your opamp is quick enough to slew its output to the input voltage in that time you allow between sampling and measuring.

If the sample capacitor is low i.e. a few pico farad then you need to take into account the added capacitance from the opamp input. You might also need to consider the opamp input noise voltage.

Finally, make sure your opamp can handle the signal range with the power rails you provide it.

Again, all these numbers are usually in the data sheet.

Answer (score 1):

A..Your opamp may or may not have back-to-back diodes across the inputs, to protect against breakdown of junctions (emitter-base, in many cases).

B..Your opamp will (guaranteed) have non-linear input capacitance, because
(1) the ESD structures will be non-linear-capacitance junctions
(2) the Miller Effect will not exist during slewing, then will kick back in during the "settling" part of the opamp behavior.
(3) cascading will affect this

A will be mentioned in the datasheet.

B is never mentioned in the datasheet, and you need to view the transistor schematic to determine truth.